# Animate image left-to-right, to show another image

Tags: html, css

I have tried to search the web for a solution on how to do this, without any luck.

What I want to achieve, is displaying one image, at the very center of the webpage.

```
<img src="image1.png">
```

Then on top of that image, I will have an identical image, just in another color.

```
<img src="image2.png">
```

At the moment, the webpage is only displaying one of the images, since they are on top of each other, and have same shape, just a different color.

The effect that I am looking for, is to change the image, infinitely, from left to right. Without the images moving at all, they should stay all centered.

Is that even possible?

Similar example, just without hovering - it should be infinitely and left to right:
http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/

Comment: Do you mean you want to cross-fade the images?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish? It is really hard to understand what you want

Comment: Questions seeking help with ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Andifined edited with example :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "infinitely", especially regarding your example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will put you on the right track. All you need to do now is change those images and play with margin, width & height on .wrap and width & height on .image-1, .image-2.

```css
html,
body { position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }

.wrap { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -100px 0 0 -100px; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
.image-1,
.image-2 { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px;  }
.image-2 { animation: my-animation 2s alternate infinite; }
.image-1 img,
.image-2 img { display: block; }

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% { width: 0%; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image-1"><img src="https://www.mirous.eu/stack-overflow/img/flake-black.png" /></div>
  <div class="image-2"><img src="https://www.mirous.eu/stack-overflow/img/flake-blue.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with small change in your CSS and the image you are going to use.

You will need both image as one image side by side. I am using below image for background.

[image]

I have added below changes in CSS.

```
.skillsDouble li {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6png9.png");
    background-position:0 0;
    ...
    ...
}

.skillsDouble li:hover {
    background-position:100% 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.skillsDouble {
    float: left;
}
.skillsDouble li {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    float:left;
    /* Old browsers */
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6png9.png");
    background-position:0 0;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 2s ease;
}
.skillsDouble li:hover {
    background-position:100% 0;
}
.skillsDouble li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="skillsDouble">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Automation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TDD</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--End skills double-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/3ct0spmr/